# Creating Self-Documenting Actors in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, rpc, actor

I'm looking at implementing a JSON-RPC based web service in Scala using [finagle](https://github.com/twitter/finagle). I'm trying to work out how best to structure the RPC invocation code (ie. taking the deserialized request and invoking the appropriate method).

The service needs to be able to spit out a help page on all the possible requests accepted and their parameters. In Java, I would simply use annotations (to both expose and document functions) and then have the RPC service reflect on the appropriate classes, detect all exposed methods and then use the reflected MethodInfo's to invoke the functions where appropriate.

What is the idiomatic Scala way to achieve something similar? Should I use a message-passing approach (ie. just pass a request object into an actor, have it determine if it can invoke it, etc.)

Comment: If you use Akka (2.1 Milestone) instead of Finagle you can use scala 2.10 and it's new reflection api to generate what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We had success doing something similar to the approach suggested by @Jan above.  More specifically, we defined a parent class for all request objects which takes the expected return type as a type parameter.  Going one step further, we're generating our protocol IDL and serialization bindings by reflecting on API objects (little more than sets of requests).

In the future, the experimental typed channels feature in Akka may help with some of the mechanics.